# How can I fix the runtime error in ecdf function in R?

Tags: r, statistics, ecdf

When I run this code-

```
a<- read.delim(file.choose("data.txt"))
d<-sort(a$d)
plot(d, sort(ecdf(d)(d)),type="s", lty=2,col="red", ylab= "P(X<=x)",ylim= 0:1)
```

it makes me make this mistake-

```
Error in ecdf(d) : 'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values
```

help?

Comment: Do you have `NA` elements.  Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: i don't think this is the case, since `sort()` removes `NA` as default (`na.last = NA`). it must be something else, but a `dput()` will definitely help..

Comment: the "data.txt" is like a vetor of numbers. there is no NA

Comment: anyway @JohnJohn, share this data with us.. we need to reproduce it in order to help you out

Comment: this is my data-  
> a
    x
1   4
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   1
6   0
7   0
8   1
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  1
14  1
15  1
16  4
17  1
18  2
19  0
20  1
21  1
22  0
23  0
24  0
25  0
26  0
27  0
28  0
29  0
30  1
31  1
32  3
33  0
34  5
35  2
36  2
37  1
38  0
39  0
40  2
41  0
42  0
43  0
44  1
45  3
46  3
47  0
48  0
49  0
50  2
51  0
52  2   and it's untill 100 lines.... its like 2 rows, but I cant do this here.

Comment: you should always copy and paste `dput()` output in your questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it seems to be alright. I've just changed the second line of your code, because the only column provided in your data was named as **x**, instead of **d**.

Check it out:

```
# load data
a = structure(list(x = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
                         1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
                         0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L,
                         0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L,
                         0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
                         6L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L,
                         3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L,
                         2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
# sort x column (the only column)
d = sort(a$x)
# plot
plot(d, sort(ecdf(d)(d)), type = "s", lty = 2, col = "red",
     ylab = "P(X<=x)", ylim = 0:1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: no, I can't edit the comment here that the data will be like it need to be. . It's a column of numbers and not a line

Comment: so use `dput()` as we asked... run `dput(a)` on your console and paste the output in your answer. we cannot guess how your data is arranged.

Comment: ok, here- > dput(a)
structure(list(x = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

Comment: well, i just ran your code with the correct `dput()` and again, there was no error..

Comment: so my code that I'v written on the post is correct? beacsue I got the same error :( - Error in ecdf(d) : 'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values

Comment: i'm not sure what is going on. try to run my code and check if there is any error. please let me know if you were successful. and give me a like if it worked for you. if it didn't, just say so and we try another way.

Comment: it works!!!! Thank you very much! . can you just explain me the meaning of why I need to write ecdf(d)(d) ? the task was to write an empirical distribution function to the data and make a plot

Comment: i didn't know the function `ecdf()` too and i did a quick search on R's documentation. it seems `ecdf()` creates a function which computes empirical cumulative distribution. therefore, when you assign this function to a variable, the variable assigned actually becomes a function. for instance, if  x = `ecdf(a)` and you can call `x(b)`, then it will comput the cumulative distribution of `b`, based on `a`, because i did `ecdf(a)` before. you can also simply do `ecdf(a)(b)` in my example, just as you did in your code. got it?